# Change file content before it committed from within commit-msg or prepare-commit-msg hooks

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-code

I'm trying modify a file within `commit-msg` or `prepare-commit-msg` hook before its committed.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the modifications are not being committed, the file is getting staged, but the changes only applied in the next commit.

Can someone point me in the right direction, what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fs = require("node:fs");
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

//get commit message
const msg = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2], "utf8");

//add message to file
const content = msg + fs.readFileSync("changes.txt", "utf8");

//save file
fs.writeFileSync("changes.txt", content);

//stage file
exec(`git add changes.txt`, (err, stdout, stderr) =>
{
    if (err)
        console.error(err);

    process.exit(~~err);
});
```

Comment: `readFileSync("../changes.txt"`, `writeFileSync("../changes.txt"`, `exec(git add changes.txt`, hm?

Comment: @phd what's the question?

Comment: Why different paths: `../changes.txt` vs `changes.txt` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, this is just an example, (literally typed it in the browser...) The actual paths are correct, they are not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pre-commit` hook is the only one that can modify the actual contents of the commit. `prepare-commit-msg` and `commit-msg` are ran later, and they cannot modify the commit contents. Also, the actual commit message is not available in `prepare-commit-msg`, only the template that the user sees.

To get the actual commit message and write it to a file that is also included in the commit itself, you would have to use a `post-commit` hook to read the commit message, write it to a file, and then amend the previous commit. This seems like a bad idea and I strongly suggests that you don't go with this path.

Comment: But in `pre-commit` the commit message is not available...

Comment: The actual commit message is not available in `prepare-commit-msg` either, it's just the prefilled text that user can modify. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why is the commit message contents relevant here?

Comment: I'm trying add the commit message into a file aka "what's new in this version" thing.

Comment: That's not possible with either `pre-commit` nor `prepare-commit-msg`. I suppose you could use a post-commit hook to modify the changes.txt file and then amend the commit, but overall this seems like a bad idea and largely reduntant. Commit messages should serve a different purpose than a user-friendly changelog.

Comment: Why do you think it's a bad idea?